# Add temporarily path to pkg-config within CMake script?

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

For external libraries the user can specify a non-standard location by adding the path to the `CMAKE_FLAGS` or by adding `-DMYLIB_ROOT`. Within the CMake script I want to find the library's pkg-config pc file. Because the pc file is not in the standard folder, it is not found by pkg-config with `FindPkgConfig`'s `pkg_search_module`.

I tried to add the user-given path to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` but it seemed to be ignored:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH "${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${MYLIB_ROOT}/lib/pkgconfig")
pkg_search_module(PKG_MYLIB mylib)

if(${PKG_MYLIB_FOUND})
...
```

When I call pkg-config from the terminal with the modified `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set, it find the pc file. What am I doing wrong? How can I get `pkg_search_module` working? I'd like to avoid calling pkg-config directly from CMake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue and a [ticket exists in CMake's bugtracker](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12926), but it is backlocked due to lack of developer interest. I guess one has to provide a patch first...

*Edit*: According to the bugtracker the feature has been implemented and is part of CMake 3.1.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe the following will do the job

```
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${MYLIB_ROOT}/lib/pkgconfig" )
```

Comment: You are right, that's the way to go when CMake 3.0 or older is used. With 3.1 it will be included automatically.