# Run a command that changes cmake's environment

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

Is it possible to execute a process from within cmake that affects cmake's own environment?

For example, I have a script that updates `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, which needs to be run in order for `pkg-config` to subsequently find my packages nicely. If I just write:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(FOO REQUIRED foo)
```

This will fail with

```
-- Checking for module 'foo'
--   No package 'foo' found
```

I need to first run:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
execute_process(COMMAND my_path_updating_script)
pkg_check_modules(FOO REQUIRED foo)
```

But while outside of cmake, this works (`pkg-config` subsequently finds `foo`), inside of cmake, this runs the process and `pkg-config` continues to fail. Is there a way to actually have the local cmake environment be updated to reflect the changes in that script? Or, otherwise, just run `pkg_check_modules()` within that new environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can alter environment variables with `set($env{..} ..)`. But often it is better to pass the right arguments to the call of the tool.

For your pkg-config example, both ways are described in the answers to this question: [Add temporarily path to pkg-config within CMake script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20447821/2799037)
Brief excerpt; use something along this:

```
set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH "${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${MYLIB_ROOT}/lib/pkgconfig")
Pkg_search_module(PKG_MYLIB mylib)
```

Comment: @Barry: Do you mind accepting this answer? Or is it not properly answered?